# CoffeeScript sort array of objects by key

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to pick up some CoffeeScript but stuck on sorting an array of objects by key. Here's what I tried:

```
sortByKey = (array, key) ->
    array.sort( (a,b) -> a[key] < b[key] ? -1 : a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : 0 )

testarr = [{i: 5, b:7}, {i:9, b:15}, {i:-4, b:-99}]
sortByKey(testarr, 'i')
val = el['b'] for el in testarr
alert val
```

My alert shows only -99, whereas I would have expected to see -99, 7, 15. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sortByKey = sortByKey(testarr, 'i')`

Comment: for numbers, it's simple: `array.sort( (a,b) -> a[key] - b[key] )`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no ternary operator in CoffeeScript. Examine your compiled JavaScript and you would be able to see this immediately.

You need to drop your nested ternary operators (which is a bad practice even in a language that supports them) and use an `if`/`else`:

```
sortByKey = (array, key) ->
  array.sort (a,b) ->
    if a[key] < b[key]
      -1
    else if a[key] > b[key]
      1
    else
      0
```

Next, your array comprehension is wrong. You've done this:

```
a = b for b in c
```

That's identical to

```
for b in c
  a = b
```

Each element is assigned in turn to `a`, and only the final `b` is left in `a` after the loop completes.

If you want to assign the result of the comprehension itself to a variable, you need parenthesis:

```
a = (b for b in c)
```

Or, in your case

```
val = (el['b'] for el in testarr)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sorted_map = Object.keys(map).sort().reduce((r, k) ->
  r[k] = map[k]
  r
, {})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).